# Csv trasform one row in 4 row

Tags: csv

i have csv file with more row with this structure:

```
+----+----+-------+------------+---------------------+--+
| ID | 1  | 2     | 3          | 4                   |  |
+----+----+-------+------------+---------------------+--+
| 5  | 12 | 500ML | 0000-00-00 | AIAB,LAV,NCCT,QC,QV |  |
+----+----+-------+------------+---------------------+--+
| 6  | 6  | 5ML   | 0000-00-00 | QV,LAV,QC,AIAB,NCCT |  |
+----+----+-------+------------+---------------------+--+
```

my goal is to achieve this with all the lines

```
+---+---+---------------------+
| 1 | 5 | 12                  |
+---+---+---------------------+
| 2 | 5 | 500ML               |
+---+---+---------------------+
| 3 | 5 | 0000-00-00          |
+---+---+---------------------+
| 4 | 5 | AIAB,LAV,NCCT,QC,QV |
+---+---+---------------------+
| 1 | 6 | 6                   |
+---+---+---------------------+
| 2 | 6 | 5ML                 |
+---+---+---------------------+
| 3 | 6 | 0000-00-00          |
+---+---+---------------------+
| 4 | 6 | AIAB,LAV,NCCT,QC,QV |
+---+---+---------------------+
```

any advice to do it?

Comment: have you tried my solution?

Answer (score 1):

Using Miller (https://github.com/johnkerl/miller) and starting from

```
ID,1,2,3,4
5,12,500ML,00000000,"AIAB,LAV,NCCT,QC,QV"
6,6,5ML,00000000,"QV,LAV,QC,AIAB,NCCT"
```

and running

```
mlr --csv --headerless-csv-output reshape -r "[0-9]" -o item,value then reorder -f item,ID,value input.csv
```

you will have

```
1,5,12
2,5,500ML
3,5,00000000
4,5,"AIAB,LAV,NCCT,QC,QV"
1,6,6
2,6,5ML
3,6,00000000
4,6,"QV,LAV,QC,AIAB,NCCT"
```

The pretty printed output

```
+------+----+---------------------+
| 1    | 5  | 12                  |
| 2    | 5  | 500ML               |
| 3    | 5  | 00000000            |
| 4    | 5  | AIAB,LAV,NCCT,QC,QV |
| 1    | 6  | 6                   |
| 2    | 6  | 5ML                 |
| 3    | 6  | 00000000            |
| 4    | 6  | QV,LAV,QC,AIAB,NCCT |
+------+----+---------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

In python you could do it using the package `pandas`:

Read the input csv file in a pandas dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('temp.csv')

    ID  1   2       3           4
0   5   12  500ML   0000-00-00  AIAB,LAV,NCCT,QC,QV
1   6   6   5ML     0000-00-00  QV,LAV,QC,AIAB,NCCT
```

Create an empty dataframe that will contain the desired structure:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A','B','C'])
```

Populate it by reading the information from your input dataframe:

```
for row in range(0,len(df)):
    for col in df.columns[1:]:
        temp = pd.DataFrame([[col,df['ID'][row],df[col][row]]], columns=['A','B','C'])
        df2 = df2.append(temp, ignore_index=True)

df2

    A   B   C
0   1   5   12
1   2   5   500ML
2   3   5   0000-00-00
3   4   5   AIAB,LAV,NCCT,QC,QV
4   1   6   6
5   2   6   5ML
6   3   6   0000-00-00
7   4   6   QV,LAV,QC,AIAB,NCCT
```

Save it as a csv file dropping index and column names:

```
df2.to_csv('temp2.csv',index=False,header=False)
```

The 'temp2.csv' file has this structure:

```
1,5,12
2,5,500ML
3,5,0000-00-00
4,5,"AIAB,LAV,NCCT,QC,QV"
1,6,6
2,6,5ML
3,6,0000-00-00
4,6,"QV,LAV,QC,AIAB,NCCT"
```